# Why am I getting invalid data from my QTouchPoint?

Tags: c++, qt, touch

I have a QGraphicsScene with QGraphicsItems.  I have reimplemented the sceneEvent function and handle multi-touch.

The problem is that randomly I get invalid values out of this section:

```
    QTouchEvent *touchEvent = static_cast<QTouchEvent *>(event);
    QList<QTouchEvent::TouchPoint> touchPoints = touchEvent->touchPoints();
    const QTouchEvent::TouchPoint &p0 = touchPoints.first();
```

Gives the following debug information (not all the time):

```
Debug: TouchUpdate: p0.scenePos(): QPointF(489.76, 160.71) :
Debug: TouchUpdate: p0.startPos(): QPointF(-8.62078e+14, 1.83351e+15)
```

I have no idea why startPos() should be a random value like that.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you blindly casting events or using a switch-case statement as below ?

```
    bool MyItem::sceneEvent(QEvent *event)
    {
        case QEvent::TouchBegin:
        case QEvent::TouchUpdate:
        case QEvent::TouchEnd:
        {
            QTouchEvent *touchEvent = static_cast<QTouchEvent *>(event);
            QList<QTouchEvent::TouchPoint> touchPoints = touchEvent->touchPoints();

            //Remember to accept the event too
            event->accept();
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is within a switch-case block as you demonstrate.  As it turns out it was fault hardware in this case.  Got a new screen and everything is working as expected.